# Ionic 2 - debugging Typescript files using source maps

Tags: debugging, angular, typescript, ionic2, safari-web-inspector

I am using Ionic 2 RC1. I want to know how to include source maps for every .ts file that is transpiled into main.js file and include their mappings in main.js.map.

Somehow when trying to debug the app loaded into an iPad connected to my Mac from Safari, I don't see .map file being loaded/visible in the network tab or resource tab. I turned on Web Inspector on my iPad.

How do I troubleshoot source map missbehaviour and what can I do to make it available in Safari, Chrome and other browsers.
Thanks,
Rad

**Update 1:**
I am using these npm packages:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.2",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
"@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
"ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"ionic-native": "2.2.3",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"zone.js": "0.6.21"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@ionic/app-scripts": "^0.0.36",
"typescript": "^2.0.3"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.36" in your dependencies packages.json file - this should do the work .

Comment: I created much longer version of this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356559/debugging-ionic-2-app-using-typescript-source-map-file-not-seen-by-vs-2015-deb In Update 1 above I listed my configuration. So I do have "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.36